# How to add sidecar MySQL in declarative Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am setting up a PHP build system and needs to run a local instance of MySQL for executing tests. Currently I am using declarative pipeline syntax and using docker. Is it possible to run MySQL as a sidecar in declarative syntax ?

If not any other method to run MySQL agent along with a custom docker image and execute migrations ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently there is [no support for sidecar containers in Jenkins declarative pipelines](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46336).

You run MySQL as a sidecar container using scripted pipeline [as shown in the Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers):

```
node {
    checkout scm
    docker.image('mysql:5').withRun('-e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw"') { c ->
        docker.image('mysql:5').inside("--link ${c.id}:db") {
          /* Wait until mysql service is up */
          sh 'while ! mysqladmin ping -hdb --silent; do sleep 1; done'
        }
        docker.image('centos:7').inside("--link ${c.id}:db") {
          /*
           * Run some tests which require MySQL, and assume that it is
           * available on the host name `db`
           */
          sh 'make check'
        }
  }
}
```

You can execute pieces of scripted pipeline in a declarative pipeline using the `<script>` tag: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script

Comment: I've tried running this pipeline on a clean job. The job just runs forever in the while loop waiting for the sql server to be ready. I'm Running jenkins inside kubernetes.

Comment: Please, could you explain why you call docker.image('mysql:5') two times ?

Comment: the code works exactly as it is in the answer. first, you boot the image, then you run wait script inside, because mysqladmin only available from inside the image, and you link to the booted DB image.